# LINQ Select Many statement

Tags: c#, linq

From MSDN Linq operators article I found below statement. I

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-09787825

SelectMany - from Assignment

```
  var orders = 
        from c in customers 
        from o in c.Orders 
        where o.Total >= 2000.0M 
        select new { c.CustomerID, o.OrderID, o.Total };
```

My question is without writing any where or join condition for the  customers and orders, how would it display only orders that are greater that 2000.0M. Wouldn't that statement create a cross join.

Comment: If "c.Orders" is a navigation property, then Entity Framework knows that there is a foreign key here and it will properly join the tables using the FK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that *query* is equivelant to this:

```
foreach(var c in customers)
{
    foreach(var o in c.Orders)
    {
        if(o.Total >= 2000.0M)
           yield return new { c.CustomerID, o.OrderID, o.Total }; 
    }
}
```

So there is no `join`. You are just filtering the `orders`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try select many. However I think this is basically doing the same thing as a join internally.

```
var orders = customers.SelectMany(c => c.Orders)
                      .Where(o => o.Total >= 2000.0M).ToList();
```